# How to set a global font - CSS

Tags: css, fonts

I want  to set a global font with CSS in one of my projects.

What I have tried is the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: HoftypeLight;
    src: Valid URL;
}

* {
    font-family: HoftypeLight;
}
```

but it seems not to work.

I know that I properly get the font because I have tried to add to one of my texts this class:

```
.test {
   font-family: HoftypeLight;
}
```

and it works.

Comment: Should it be `* {font-family: HoftypeMedium}` ?

Comment: My aim is to add this font to every class so I guess that with * I am doing that

Comment: HoftypeMedium / HoftypeLight ? To every class or to the whole page in general? :root {...} html, body {...} etc.

Comment: Oh, now I get what were you asking. That was a type, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think use like this

```
body {
  font-family: Algerian;
}
```

font same for in all project within the body tag.